# While shows only one result

Tags: php

I've got this code:

```
<?php
    include("config.php"); // mysql connect and mysql(i) filter sanitize

     $cislonakupus=$_GET['cislonakupu'];
     $su=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `count_size` WHERE `cislonakupu`='$cislonakupus'");
        
     while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($su)) {
            $pid1=$row['idproduktu'];
            $s9=$row['S'];
            echo $s9;
            die();
     }
?>
```

And my table have two records, as shown below.

> [DATABASE]
>
> Table "count_size"
>
> cislonakupu= 123 , S = 1
>
> cislonakupu= 123 , S = 2

`echo` only prints out the first record `S` as 1, and does not display the second record with `S` as 2.

Why is that so?

Comment: Because you `die()` in the middle of the loop!  `exit()/die()` terminate execution immediately and abruptly.

Comment: I'm wondering how many answers this question will get. I think we can push 4!

Answer (score 1):

You have a die in the loop

```
<?php
    include("config.php"); // mysql connect and mysql(i) filter sanitize

$cislonakupus=$_GET['cislonakupu'];
$su=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `count_size` WHERE `cislonakupu`='$cislonakupus'");
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($su)) {
            $pid1=$row['idproduktu'];
    $s9=$row['S'];
            echo $s9;
            die(); // Remove this, it stops the script
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You clearly say `die()` which terminates your program.

Answer (score 0):

Move `die();` outside the while loop